# Swift Google Maps: Opening Google Maps app and drop a pin

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am attempting to open a location on Google Maps app from my app, and I am able to do it successfully, zoomed to the desired location.

However, it is it possible to drop a pin at that particular location as well? I followed the instruction here but does not seem to include any on opening Google Maps app and dropping pins. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme